# How to select range of columns in a dataframe based on variables?

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I have dataframe like that:

```
              id   price  side    size  symbol
0    15599002600  9974.0  Sell    2151  XBTUSD
1    15599002650  9973.5  Sell     501  XBTUSD
2    15599002700  9973.0  Sell     192  XBTUSD
3    15599002800  9972.0  Sell     377  XBTUSD
4    15599002900  9971.0  Sell    4300  XBTUSD
5    15599002950  9970.5  Sell      25  XBTUSD
```

Im trying to get slice of row from some price to some price.
So, im using loc method.

```
newdf = order_book.loc[price_1st  : price_2nd, 'price']
```

As variable i have that:

```
price_1st = 9973.0
price_2nd = 9971.0
```

But im getting that: `Series([], Name: price, dtype: float64)`

What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need set the `index`

```
price_1st = 9973.0
price_2nd = 9971.0
df.set_index('price').loc[price_1st:price_2nd]
                 id  side  size  symbol
price                                  
9973.0  15599002700  Sell   192  XBTUSD
9972.0  15599002800  Sell   377  XBTUSD
9971.0  15599002900  Sell  4300  XBTUSD
```

Or

```
df[df.price.between(price_2nd,price_1st)]
            id   price  side  size  symbol
2  15599002700  9973.0  Sell   192  XBTUSD
3  15599002800  9972.0  Sell   377  XBTUSD
4  15599002900  9971.0  Sell  4300  XBTUSD
```

Or

```
df.query("price>=@price_2nd and price<=@price_1st")
```

Comment: Thx, it worked. And how to use summ of 'size'? I was trying set index first, as i wrote , and after that use sum() there. `newdf2 = df.set_index('size').sum()`

Comment: `df['price'].between(price_2nd,price_1st, inclusive=False)`   for strict inequalities.

Answer (score 1):

You can try,

```
df.query('price_1st <= price <= price_2nd')
```

OR

```
(price_1st <= df['price']) & (df['price'] < price_2nd)
```

Comment: Its more simple way in my opinion, thx And how to use summ of 'size'? I was trying set index first, as wenyoben wrote, and after that use sum() there. `newdf2 = df.set_index('size').sum()`

Comment: @Andry, thnx for liking the solution :-)  i think you simply can try `df.query('price_1st <= price <= price_2nd')['size'].sum()`  let me know if works.

Comment: its not =). `price_1st is not defined` So, i tried  `f = df.query(price_1st <= 'price'<= price_2nd)['size'].sum()` And i get this: `id                                           41476787048300
price                                           3.61295e+07
side      SellSellSellSellSellSellSellSellSellSellSellSe...
symbol    XBTUSDXBTUSDXBTUSDXBTUSDXBTUSDXBTUSDXBTUSDXBTU...
dtype: object` But im tryind to get just sum of one row